# How to integrate my java application with Google Home?

Tags: google-home

I am trying to integrate my java app to google home.

Agenda : Taking the input from the google home as request and sending it to my application as a request parameter and giving back the response to the Google home. This is my agenda.

I am new to google home so if anyone knows how to do this please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into the [Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/) platform.

Actions run in the cloud, not on a device. Your Assistant device (such as a Google Home) acts like a browser.

There is a [Java/Kotlin library](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/java/overview) available.